# why is cordova using Web SQL is deprecated?

Tags: ios, sql, cordova, web

var db = window.openDatabase('sap', '1.0', 'sap Database', 5*1024*1024);

We are using this in ios cordova application for local storage database, getting UnknownError: Web SQL is deprecated. Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

WebSQL has been deprecated in most browsers/webview. You should now use IndexedDb.